# Expand/Collapse Win Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to create UI like this in Windows form application C#. 
First my form should appear like this when the chechBox is not checked.

[image]

And if the checkBox checked my form changes to like this

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: what is the problem. When some tried to learn something new the experts doesn't help but down vote the newbie questions. I have searched on google before posting the question.

Comment: You can create form by using dynamic layout (at least partially, e.g. some content can be put into normal `Panel`s, but then they are a part of dynamic layout) with the help of `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel`. Then if you set `Autosize`/`AutosizeMode` properties of controls (including form itself) they will shrink/expand on a simple visibility change. E.g. on checkbox set you make `panelAdvancedOptions` visible, which lies inside `TableLayoutPanel`, which grows in size and cause form (which also has `Autosize` set) to grow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of the form dynamically on `CheckedChanged` event of check box. Don't forget to set anchor of below fields or set visible on expand and invisible on collapse.

EDIT: The most simple way to achieve the results is given below.

```
private readonly int _collapsedHeight;
public Form1()
{
    //Set Anchor of Connect button to Right and Bottom and leave default for others
    //Optionally you need to hide controls except Connect button on collapse and vice versa.
    //Set Form Border Style to FixedSingle and MaximizeBox to false           
    InitializeComponent();
    _collapsedHeight = Height;
}

private void chkAdvancedOption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set Y value to collapse eg. 140, adjust it as required...
    Height = chkAdvancedOption.Checked ? _collapsedHeight + 140 : _collapsedHeight;
}
```

Comment: 2 downvotes actually - this doesn't answer the question. Changing the height won't display hidden controls. Pushing them outside the normal boundaries is painful, unnecessary and won't achieve the same effect -  the buttons will appear below the `Connect` button. WIndows Forms uses layout [Panels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued) and docking to handle changing contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can do this and achieve the same result. then?

Comment: +1 This is a valid way to achieve the result. All the OP needs to do is set the form size in code when the checkbox is changed and anchor the connect button to the bottom of the form. Good answer

Comment: Changing the height of form on run time but doesn't working @M.NasserJavaid

Comment: No as shown in question pictures I want to show advance option when checkbox is checked. Problem is when form loads the advance option are visible and checking and unchecking the checkbox doesn't work. @M.NasserJavaid

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid it works but there is still problem. Labels and text box that should visible on advance option check are visible when form loads.
I think there is problem in this project. I have created another project and tried changing height method and it worked.

Comment: @Hanni By default form must be in collapsed form, and expand on checkbox checked state at runtime according to your need in Y.

Comment: Form is collapsed but loaded in nor in collapsed or expand mode. @M.NasserJavaid

Comment: Make sure that you are not changing the height or width in other code except `chkAdvancedOption_CheckedChanged`

Comment: It must be appear as you adjust in designer, and after that expand in case of check box state changed

Comment: @Hanni In other way, you can design collapse able control. You can get idea from the given link or it may possible you may find ready made.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818284/why-custom-control-task-pane-does-not-update-its-properties

Answer (score -1):

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Manually register the event-handling method for the   
     // CheckedChanged event of the CheckBox control.
     checkbox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.Check_Clicked);
  }

void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
  **//This is only sample code**
    // do your code

    if (panel2.Visible) 
    {
    panel2.Visible = false;
    cmdAdvanced.Visible = true;
    }
   }
```